# AttributeError when using a pyqt4 event

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I have some pyqt4 script like this: (edit)

```
self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    self.close_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.closeApp)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Main App", None))
    self.close_pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Close", None))

def closeApp(self, event):
    result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit Application',
          "Are you sure you want to exit?",
          QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
       event.accept()
    else:
       event.ignore()
```

when I run the script, there always shows error message like this:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'accept'

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Clearly `event` is a `bool`. Without seeing more, it's hard to say precisely why. Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows others to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Surely your `closeApp` function should look like:

```
def closeApp(self):  # event not required
    result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit Application',
                                        "Are you sure you want to exit?",
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.close()
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close for info regarding `close()`.

Hope this helps.